# Identify the template name in joomla site

Tags: templates, fix-my-code

Please visit this [link](http://naadiastrology.info/).

Which template is used by this above site?

Please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this,

Your template name is `corpoboost` this can be easily figure out using page source of the browser.

`/templates/corpoboost/css/template.css`

other options is login to administartor of the site

Extension -> Template manager - >check default site template.

Hope it helps..

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your reply. Can you please help me in changing slideshow text. Here on slideshow images, you can see text : "Photo gallery, online payment, naadi astrology".

How and where to edit those text in admin.

Please help me to find solution.

Comment: I thinks its a banner module go to admin > components ->banners check the corresponding image there you will find an image description too.

Comment: is i have to change in code? i hope no. i will check in admin.

Comment: hi, here i got it: For built in slider just go to your template manager > Corpoboost – Default > Slider options just fill images and caption text then save it. thanks for your support.